How to initialise one part of a list in the front end before the second part is loaded? (Blazor Server)
I'm experimenting with the ChatGPT API. I want the user prompt to be shown in a message before the GPT answer is loaded, but its refusing to do anything until both are loaded.
My Initial Code was this (the most important part is the one with the comments i think):
<div class="messages">
    @{
        foreach (var Interaction in Interactions) {
            <div class="message-circle">
                @Interaction.Prompt
            </div>
            <div class="message-left">
              @{
                if (Interaction.Answer != null)
                { @Interaction.Answer.Content[0].Text; }
                else 
                {
                  <span>...</span>
                }
              }
            </div> 
        }
    }

</div>


<form class="messageBox" @onsubmit="SubmitInput">

  <input class="messageInput" type="text"
   placeholder="Input prompt!" id="messageInput"
   @bind="UserInput" @bind:event="oninput"/>

  <button type="submit" id="sendButton">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 664 663">
path stuff...
    </svg>
  </button>
</form>

@code {
  private string UserInput { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  private List<GPTInteraction> Interactions = new List<GPTInteraction>();

  private async Task SubmitInput()
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInput))
    {
        // Add the prompt to the list with a "null" answer initially
      var interaction = new GPTInteraction(UserInput, null, Interactions.Count);
      Interactions.Add(interaction);

      // Clear input field
      UserInput = string.Empty;

      // Notify the UI
      StateHasChanged();

      // Get the response asynchronously
      var completion = await GPTAPIResultService.LoadGPTResultAsync(interaction.Prompt);

      // Update the placeholder with the actual completion
      interaction.Answer = completion;

      // Notify the UI
      StateHasChanged();
    }
  }

}
 

The Class this list is based of:
using OpenAI.Chat;

namespace GPTStandards.Data.GPTAPI;
public class GPTInteraction(string prompt, ChatCompletion? completion, int id)
{
    public string Prompt { get; set; } = prompt;
    public ChatCompletion? Answer { get; set; } = completion;
    public int ID { get; set; } = id;
}


StateHasChanged(); await Task.Yield(); Some say Delay(1). I have not experienced the "issue" however this yields the control to the UI thread so the screen update can occur.

Thank you so much! await Task.Yield() worked! Tomorrow ill look into the logic behind it but for now my Site works :DD

InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)

@flackoverstow - why (do you think that would help)?
